# VKScript, хранимая процедура. Не удается вызвать

Tags: vkontakte-api, vkscript

Написал такую хранимую процедуру:

```
var q = Args.q;
var count = Args.count;

var groups = API.groups.search({
    "q": q,
    "count": count
});

var result = [];

if (groups.length == 0) {
    return [];
} else {
    var i = 0;
    while (i < groups.items.length) {
        var members = API.groups.getMembers({
            "group_id": groups.items[i].id,
            "count": 0
        }).count;
        result = result + [{
            "group": groups.items[i],
            "members": members
        }];
        i = i + 1;
    }
}

return result;
```

Она возвращает список найденных групп вместе с кол-вом человек в этой группе. В веб-окружении ВК она работает отлично.

Пытаюсь ее использовать в своем приложении:

```
https://api.vkontakte.ru/method/execute.getSourceInfo?access_token=' + self.accessToken + 'q=' + name + '&count=3' + '&callback=JSON_CALLBACK
```

Получаю ошибку:

> "User authorization failed: invalid access_token (4)."

И это при том, что все методы, которые используются в процедуре, при вызове из приложения напрямую - работают идеально.

Что за магия?

**Обновление от 13.10.2016**

Строка с вызовом метода теперь формируется так:

```
'https://api.vk.com/method/execute.getSourceInfo?access_token=' + self.accessToken + '&q=' + name + '&count=3' + '&version=5.57&callback=JSON_CALLBACK'
```

Но хранимая процедура все равно не выполняется. Ошибки:

```
error_code: 7
error_msg: "Permission to perform this action is denied"
method: "groups.search"

error_code: 7
error_msg: "Permission to perform this action is denied"
method: "execute.getSourceInfo"
```

Так же я предположил, что нужно явно передавать токен методу `groups.search`, но и это не помогло:

```
var q = Args.q;
var count = Args.count;
var access_token = Args.access_token;

var groups = API.groups.search({
    "q": q,
    "count": count,
    "access_token": access_token,
});
...
```

В общем, не понимаю в чем проблема.

**Обновление от 14.10.2016**

Удалось таки получить доступ к выполнению хранимой процедуру. По совету @terron запросил доступ к группам (`groups`). Теперь возникла следующая проблема - ответ пустой при вызове на клиенте. При вызове в окружении ВК - работает нормально:

```
var q = Args.q;
var count = Args.count;

var groups = API.groups.search({
    "q": q,
    "count": count
});

var result = [];

if (groups.length == 0) {
    return [];
} else {
    // Все, что добавляется в results в этом цикле - не доступно при вызове. 
    // При чем, если вызывать процедуру в окружении ВК - все работает.
    var i = 0;
    while (i < groups.items.length) {
        var members = API.groups.getMembers({
            "group_id": groups.items[i].id,
            "count": 0
        }).count;
        result = result + [{
            "group": groups.items[i],
            "members": members
        }];
        i = i + 1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Вызываю процедуру так (AngularJS):

```
var findContentSource = function(name) {
    var self = this;
    return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
        $http.jsonp(
            'https://api.vk.com/method/execute.getSourceInfo?q=' + window.encodeURIComponent(name) + '&count=3&version=5.58&callback=JSON_CALLBACK&access_token=' + self.accessToken
        ).success(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы потеряли `&` при конкатенации токена со строкой. Ваша строка:

```
https://api.vkontakte.ru/method/execute.getSourceInfo?access_token=' + self.accessToken + 'q=' + name + '&count=3' + '&callback=JSON_CALLBACK
```

А должно быть так:

```
https://api.vkontakte.ru/method/execute.getSourceInfo?access_token=' + self.accessToken + '&q=' + name + '&count=3' + '&callback=JSON_CALLBACK
```

Также не забывайте указывать версию API в параметре `v` и используйте в качестве API-эндпоинта `api.vk.com`, а не `api.vkontakte.ru` - этот эндпоинт считается устаревшим и [скоро будет отключен](https://vk.com/wall-1_340402).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, исправил указанные вами ошибки, но это не помогло. Свой вопрос обновил.

Comment: При авторизации пользователя вы пробовали запрашивать доступ к сообществам?

Comment: хм, ни где не написано, что нужен доступ к сообществам, но оно решил проблему с доступом. Правда, теперь ВСЕГДА приходит пустой результат.

Comment: При передаче параметра `q` в ваш execute-метод вы делаете URL-кодирование? Ваш метод у меня прекрасно запускается как из веб-окружения ВКонтакте, так и при обращении к нему через API.

Comment: Вы про encodeURIComponent? Если да, то это не помогло. В ответ сейчас добавлю код, который полностью иллюстрирует вызов метода.

Comment: Проблема определенно в вашем Angular-коде. Я, к сожалению, в Angular не разбираюсь, но найденный на просторах Stack Overflow [пример JSONP-запроса на Angular](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13400409/4981937) оказался рабочим. Вот адаптированный вариант, только свой рабочий токен подставьте: https://jsfiddle.net/terron/r0yhf0gx/5/ - все работает.

Comment: таки разобрался. Проблема была в том, что я писал вместо `v` - `version`. Из за этого и не работал код. Награда придет через 18 часов.